# React Redux breaking on page routing

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Hello so I have added redux to the project(Ecom site) that I am working on, so I am fetching products with the help of Redux, I just then added another redux Action for when the user clicks on the product to view the details so it works and I do get back the results that I expect but now the problem is when I page route to a page which has redux I get an error until I reload the page and everything works perfectly

**Code to my store**

```
import { combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { HoodiesFecthReducer } from "./Reducers/ProductsFecthReducer/HoodiesFetchReducer";
import { JacketsFetchReducer } from "./Reducers/ProductsFecthReducer/JacketsFecthReducer";
import productDetailsFetchReducer from "./Reducers/ProductsFecthReducer  /ProductDetailsFetchReducer";
import { T_ShirtsFetchReducer } from "./Reducers/ProductsFecthReducer/T-ShirtFetchReducer";

const initialState = {};

const reducers = combineReducers({
  Hoodies: HoodiesFecthReducer,
  Jackets: JacketsFetchReducer,
  T_Shirts: T_ShirtsFetchReducer,
  ProductDetail: productDetailsFetchReducer,
});

const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
export const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);
```

**Code below is one of the action that fetches the product so I will add in one because they are all the same I avoid adding tons of code that are performing same task**

```
import {
  PRODUCT_FETCH_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_FETCH_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_FETCH_SUCCESS,
} from "./actionTypes";
import axios from "axios";

export const JacketsFetchAction = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/clothes/jackets";
 
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_FETCH_REQUEST });
    const { data } = await axios.get(url);
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_FETCH_FAIL, payload: error });
  }
};
```

**So now things started breaking when I added this action to the mix**

```
import {
  PRODUCT_FETCH_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_FETCH_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_FETCH_SUCCESS,
} from "./actionTypes";
import axios from "axios";

const productDetailFetchAction = (productID, productCategory) => async (
  dispatch
) => {
  const url = `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/clothes/product-detail/${productCategory}    /${productID}`;

  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_FETCH_REQUEST });
    const { data } = await axios.get(url);
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_FETCH_FAIL, payload: error });
  }
};

export default productDetailFetchAction;
```

Comment: Are you using redux-thunk for asynchronous dispatch? Because else redux won't be able to handle that.

Comment: Yes if you check the store code I have made use of redux-thunk